# How to return the first index when the value are greater than something

Tags: python, pandas

This is to simulate the "Knock out" situations in the structured investment. Generally, there are three stocks: Stock A; Stock B; Stock C, and their prices are observed monthly to check whether they are above 100% of the price of first month (KO level).

The basic dataframe looks like this:

```
           Stock-A Stock-B Stock-C
2010-01-01   10      20       40
2010-02-01   9.5     18       31
2010-03-01   10.5    22       39
2010-04-01   11.5    23       36
```

If one of their prices going above the KO level, the function should return the month and do not need to monitor the price any more.

For example, the stock-A across the KO level at 2010-03-01, so the function should label this as a successful "Knocked-out" stock as well as return the date, which is 2010-03-01.

If there is a stock never across the line, the function should iterate over the end and return this as a non-knocked out stock.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note:  I edited Stock-C to be a non-knocked out stock.  Otherwise, all 3 are knocked out stocks and answers can't check for non-knocked out stocks.

Comment: Thanks John, any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt, with some assumptions (plus, take this with a grain of salt: I don't claim to be a Pandas expert, just thought this would be an interesting problem to work on)

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'date': '2010-01-01', 'stock_a': 10, 'stock_b': 20, 'stock_c': 30},
    {'date': '2010-01-02', 'stock_a': 9.5, 'stock_b': 18, 'stock_c': 31},
    {'date': '2010-03-01', 'stock_a': 10.5, 'stock_b': 22, 'stock_c': 39},
    {'date': '2010-04-01', 'stock_a': 11.5, 'stock_b': 23, 'stock_c': 36},
])
# Assuming you want the first chronological record of such an event
df = df.sort_values(['date', 'stock_a', 'stock_b', 'stock_c'])
df2 = pandas.concat([
    df['stock_a'] > df['stock_a'][0],
    df['stock_b'] > df['stock_b'][0],
    df['stock_c'] > df['stock_c'][0],
], axis=1)
df2['date'] = True
# At this point columns stock_{a,b,c} are populated with NaN in place where the value
# was less than the first observation
df3 = df[df2].query('stock_a == stock_a & stock_b == stock_b & stock_c == stock_c')

if not df3.empty:
    print df3.iloc[[0]]
print 'No match'
```